# Completeness of Landau basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, hilbert-space, wavefunction, mathematical-physics

We know that the Landau Hamiltonian (uniform magnetic field) is diagonalized by wavefunctions $|n,m\rangle,n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ in the symmetric gauge. However, does this set of functions form a "complete" basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$? I would think the answer is yes, but I can't quite think of a rigorous proof.

Comment: Since you are generally talking about spatially localized energy eigenstate wave functions in an unbounded physical plane, the precise boundary conditions in effect can become fairly important.  I may be able to track down a comprehensive discussion of this in a few days.

Comment: @Buzz I don't quite understand what you mean. For example, the eigenstates generated by the quantum oscillator (which are also spatially localized) indeed form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (with no appeal to boundary conditions since the system is presumably infinite). A rigorous proof could be found in Brian Hall's *Quantum theory for mathematicians*

Comment: @Buzz Congratulations on getting your nomination for mod. I voted for you at #1. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution, so I will provide a sketch of the proof. Notice that the ladder operators can be written as
$$
a^* = -i\left(D-\frac{\bar{z}}{2}\right),\quad b^* = -i\left(\bar{D} -\frac{z}{2}\right)
$$
where $z,\bar{z} = x\pm iy$ and $D,\bar{D} = D_z,D_{\bar{z}}$.

Let $N,M\in \mathbb{N}$ and
$$
V_{N,M}= \text{span}\left\{ z^\alpha  \bar{z}^\beta e^{-|z|^2/2}:\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{N},\alpha-\beta =M,\beta \le N\right\}
$$
Using induction, it's not too hard to show that for all $M\ge 0$, the family of Landau states $|0,M\rangle,|1,M+1\rangle,...,|N,M+N\rangle$ form a basis for $V_{N,M}$. Hence, $|0,M\rangle,|1,M+1\rangle,...$ forms a basis for $V_M = \bigcup V_{N,M}$. A similar statement can be made for $M<0$. Hence, the Landau states form a  basis for
$$
V = \text{span}\left\{ z^\alpha  \bar{z}^\beta e^{-|z|^2/2}:\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
Notice that $V$ is also equal to
$$
V = \text{span}\left\{x^\alpha y^\beta e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}:\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
It should be noted that (see Brian Hall *Quantum theory for Mathematicians* section 11.4 for proof)
$$
\sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{(ipx)^\alpha}{\alpha!}\to_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} e^{ipx-x^2/2}
$$
Therefore, we see that $e^{i(px+qy)} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$ is in the $L^2$ closure of $V$.
Now suppose that $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is orthogonal to all the Landau states. Then it must be orthogonal to $e^{i(px+qy)} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$. Therefore,
$$
\iint dx dy e^{-i(px+qy)} e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\psi(x,y) =0
$$
Hence, the Fourier transform of $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\psi(x,y)$ is zero everywhere, and thus $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\psi(x,y)=0$ and thus $\psi(x,y)=0$.